# Simple React Native Image Game is Lagging.How do i optimize?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, game-development

I am trying to implement a simple img tapping game with react native for learning purposes.I am using this librarys https://github.com/bberak/react-native-game-engine game loop component as a game loop.

What I am trying to do is render some imgs with random locations on screen with small radius then increase it up to a value, after decrease it and finally remove the img from screen (or when tapped) - just like in this game: http://mouseaccuracy.com/

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Dimensions, View,ToastAndroid,TouchableOpacity,Image,Text } from "react-native";



    const { width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get("window");
    import { GameLoop } from "react-native-game-engine";
    import { Fonts } from '../utils/Fonts';
    import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'
    import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
    import SwordImage from "../assets/tapfight/sword.png";
    import ShieldImage from "../assets/tapfight/shield.png";


          this.renderSwordOrCircle(circle)
        )


            })




    )




    }


       }

     renderHealth = () =>{
    return(
      <View>
        <View style={{ alignItems:'center' ,position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0}}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily:Fonts.MainFont,color:'white',fontSize:25}}>{this.playerHealth}</Text>
        <Progress.Bar color='red' progress={this.playerHealth/100} width={100} height={18} />

        </View>
        <View style={{ alignItems:'center',position: "absolute", top: 0, right: 0}}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily:Fonts.MainFont,color:'white',fontSize:25}}>{this.enemyHealth}</Text>
        <Progress.Bar  color='red' progress={this.enemyHealth/100} width={100} height={18} />
         <FastImage resizeMode="contain" style={{width:100,height:100}} source={require('../assets/tapfight/guard_2_head.png')}></FastImage>
        </View>

      </View>


    )



     }


      render() {
        if(this.state.fight==true){
          return (
            <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'transparent'}} > 
             <GameLoop style={{flex:1}} onUpdate={this.updateCircle}> 
             {this.renderHealth()} 
             {this.renderCircles()}     
             </GameLoop>       
             </View>

          );

        }else{

    return(
      null
    )

        }

      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      }
    });
```

What i am doing is i am generating images every 600 ms on screen and player tries to tap them.The problem is when there is more than 2 images on screen fps drops significantly.Tested in android actual device.I am updating state once at the end of updateCircle function.
Game loop is updateCircle component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to animate a component that is **not made for being animated**.

I dont know well the FastImage component, but I understand that it purpose is to pre-load images, not animate.

You shoud use Animated.Image for the image, and Animated.timing for managing the animations of Animated.Image